# Read a file with numbers and save it to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to read a file with numbers and save it to an array, my file extension is pgm, See the file [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZknk.png)

## My code:

```
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("coisa2.pgm", "r");

//read file into array
int numberArray[250001];
int i;

if (myFile == NULL){
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
}

for (i = 3; i < 250001; i++){
    fscanf(myFile, "%d\n", &numberArray[i] );
}

for (i = 0; i < 250001; i++){
    printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
}

fclose(myFile);

return 0;
```

## Output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnaVH.png)
it should output numbers like 255 or 0

Comment: I guess you want to skip the first 3 lines, that why you begin the I at 3. But you use this I to write in your array, you don't skip the firsts lines with this.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Include the file in your question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: yes im trying to skip the first 3 lines of the file. My question is why my output is random numbers when should be numbers like 255

Comment: You need to consume 9 words before getting to the numbers: `scanf("%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s");`

Comment: You should **always** check the number of parsed fields. The return value of `scanf`is not to be ignored.

Comment: You would probably be better off reading a line at a time with fgets, ignoring the first 3 reads, and then using atoi() to convert the strings to ints for the remaining lines.

Comment: It is not a "file with numbers", it is an ASCII Portable GrayMap file; or more formally, P2 format Netpbm file. You cannot parse the header fields with `scanf()`. First, read the two first characters in the file, and verify they are `'P'` and `'2'`.  Next, use my `pnm_value()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45002488/1475978) to read the next three header fields (`width`, `height`, and `maxval`). Then, you can read the numbers (between 0 and `maxval`, inclusive) using `fscanf()`.